# Angular2 + ExpressJs <app-root> dosen't load.

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I did read all the other topics but none of the solutions solved my problem.

I write npm start and the server is working as it should but app-root does not it seems like it does not load the client (Angular 2 app).

I just get an empty html page with:

Loading...

(look at my html file down the page)

any idea what can cause it - or any suggested solution ?
Thank you.

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')


//Set up default mongoose connection
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/beatblocks';

// Get Mongoose to use the global promise library
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, function(err) {
    if (err){
        console.log("error connecting to db...")
    }
    console.log("connected to database...");
});


// Load Songs Model
require('./models/songs');
const songs = mongoose.model('songs');

// Load Locations Model
require('./models/locations');
const locations = mongoose.model('locations');

// Load users Model
require('./models/users');
const users = mongoose.model('users');


var routeIndex = require('./routes/index');
var routeSongs = require('./routes/songs');
var routeUsers = require('./routes/users');
//var routeLocations = require('./routes/locations');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();


// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src')));

//View Engine
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/', routeIndex);
app.use('/songs', routeSongs);
app.use('/users', routeUsers);
//app.use('/locations', routeLocations);

module.exports = app;
```

www.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('beatblocksweb:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

my index.html :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beat Blocks</title>
</head>
<body>
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<app-header></app-header>
</body>
</html>
```

my project :

[image]

Comment: I think you have multiple static folders and that's confusing Node.js.  I would reference only the `dist` directory as that is what's holding all your static assets, including the all-important `index.html`.  Try enabling only the static folder to see if that helps.  Also, are your routes API calls?  Do you use EJS templates in your app?

Comment: Works great now. thank you !

Comment: Great! Glad I could help